# Mapping of multiple @queryParam into a single object

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jackson, jax-rs

I have a localService which I want to access via our restful api:

```
@GET
@Path("/some/path")
OutputObject doSomeSpecialCalculation(@QueryParam("input") InputObject obj);
```

Following problem/problems - what would be the best approach:

- To be able to create the InputObject, I need a lot of different input data -> the consturctor looks something like that: new InputObject(Obj1 o1, Obj2 o2, ..., Obj6 o6);

**Q1: Is it possible to map many queryParams into a single object?**

- The next problem is that most of the parameters (obj_n) need a special ParamProvider for construction. (e.g. the rest call for Obj2 o2 is an id number and the ParamConverter maps the id to the correct object)

I could create a new local service method like that:

```
@GET
@Path("/some/path")
OutputObject doSomeSpecialCalculation(@QueryParam("obj1") Obj1 ob1, @QueryParam("obj2") Obj2 ob2, ...);
```

Then I could create multiple ParamProviders for each obj_n and it would work, but I don't want to create duplicated methods in our localservices.

**Q2: Would there be a better solution for my particular problem?**

**TL;DR:**

- I have a local service method which takes a ComplexObject as an input parameter
- I want to access that method via a rest call
- To create that ComplexObject I need multiple objects as parameters for the constructor
- The most of the multiple parameters need a special mapper/converter: Restful-Input: id -> Object

It would be awesome if I could solve this problem just with annotations: @JsonTypeInfo on the complex object, and some "use-that-converter"-annotations on the input objects of the complex object's constructor.

Regards,

(using jackson 1.9/jboss eap 6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @BeanParam annotation on the Endpoint's method argument (your custom class) and use all the needed @QueryParam, @Header etc. values on fields of the custom class.

And this is how it looks like for a POST with JSON:

JSON:

```
{
    "user_name" : "Chewbacca",
    "year_of_birth" : 1977
}
```

Java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class SimpleRequest {

    @NotNull
    private final String userName;

    @Min(1900)
    private final int yearOfBirth;

    @JsonCreator
    public SimpleRequest(@JsonProperty("user_name") String userName,
                         @JsonProperty("year_of_birth") int yearOfBirth) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public int getYearOfBirth() {
        return yearOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just researched that approach and it looks quite good. Could work for GET requests with a complex parameter.

Do you also have an approach for a Post ('someValue method(ComplexObject obj)), where the ComplexObject received through the posted body as json.

Currently I am parsing the json by hand with a MessageBodyWriter implementation, but it would be much cleaner if I could just provide a mapper who could transform json into a ComplexObject. And if a ComplexObject would use ComplexObject1 as a member variable, the mapper would search for a mapper for ComplexObject1

Comment: Sure, see my other answer.